# Copy object to array converts it to string

Tags: php

In a wordpress plugin I'm writing a script to copy a bunch of WP_POST objects. I don't think it matters for this question what type of object it is I have or what data it has, I'm trying to simply copy the object to an array with the code below and I get the error Object could not be converted to string. Several objects can be copied before this error is thrown so maybe it is something to do with the data but I'm printing it out and it looks fine to me.

Why is saving the object to the array trying to convert it to a string?

```
$result['post'] = $post;
```

> Uncaught Error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to
> string in
> /home/staticfiles/staging.webbskisser.se/karlshamnwcag/wp-content/plugins/kpm/admin/class-kpm-admin-ajax.php
> on line 214

Comment: Does the error happen at the time of the assignment or are you then trying to do something to the array of objects?

Comment: @apokryfos At the time of copy, line 214 is the above copied line, I've done some further testing and I'm able to convert the data to json and I can store that in the array

Comment: Is the `$result` array something you've made? Is it an array or an object that implements `ArrayAccess` ?

Comment: @apokryfos the $result array is declared like so $result = array(); it also contains another object that is assigned after its creation like so $result['taxonomies'] = $taxonomies; Nothing in the array is manipulated after it has been added to it. The end goal is to json_encode the array and assign it as a data attribut to a html element which will later be read by javascript

Comment: Its now working after I reverted back to my old code before I tested json_encoding it, I've compared the code I had when I posted this with the code I had at the time and its exactly the same but its no longer giving this error so I guess it must have somehow been something with the server, I haven't changed anything about the data either. Thank you for your time apokryfos.